# Phoenix/Ecto - changeset error when updating embeds_many record

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In my Phoenix app, I am getting a `no function clause matching in Ecto.Changeset.change/2` error when trying to update a model with an `embeds_many` relationship. I've read the docs and seen other posts about this, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

First off, here's the error:

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Ecto.Changeset.change/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:307: Ecto.Changeset.change(%{"content" => "<p>Nice to see you</p>", "duration" => 15, "id" => "93387d2d-a6ed-4902-911f-4dc1525aca2b"}, %{})
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:196: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.on_replace/2
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset/relation.ex:299: Ecto.Changeset.Relation.reduce_delete_changesets/5
    (ecto) lib/ecto/changeset.ex:691: Ecto.Changeset.cast_relation/4
    (myapp) web/models/agenda.ex:20: MyApp.Agenda.changeset/2
```

The 'parent' model is `Agenda`, and the embedded model is `AgendaPage`. The models are defined as follows:

`agenda.ex`

```
defmodule MyApp.Agenda do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  @primary_key {:id, :string, []}
  @derive {Phoenix.Param, key: :id}
  schema "agenda" do
    field :name, :string
    embeds_many :pages, MyApp.AgendaPage, on_replace: :delete
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:name])
    |> cast_embed(:pages)
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

`agenda_page.ex`

```
defmodule MyApp.AgendaPage do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  embedded_schema do
    field :content, :string
    field :duration, :integer
  end

  def changeset(struct, params \\ %{}) do
    struct
    |> cast(params, [:content, :duration])
  end
end
```

And the `update` action from `agenda_controller.ex`

```
def update(conn, %{"id" => id, "agenda" => agenda_params}) do
  agenda = Repo.get!(Agenda, id)
  changeset = Agenda.changeset(agenda, agenda_params)

  case Repo.update(changeset) do
    {:ok, agenda} ->
      json conn, %{status: "ok", agenda: agenda}
    {:error, changeset} ->
      errors = parse_errors(changeset)
      IO.inspect errors
      json(conn |> put_status(400), %{status: "error", message: "Failed to update Agenda", errors: errors})
  end
end
```

In the `iex` terminal, I can access an existing agenda with `MyApp.Repo.get(MyApp.Agenda, "default_agenda")`, which gives back the following record:

```
%MyApp.Agenda{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "agenda">,
 id: "default_agenda", name: "Default Agenda",
 pages: [%{"content" => "<p>This is the default agenda</p>", "duration" => 10,
"id" => "0849862a-0794-4466-88a3-6052da360ca0"},
%{"content" => "<p>Nice to see you</p>", "duration" => 15,
"id" => "93387d2d-a6ed-4902-911f-4dc1525aca2b"}]}
```

An example of the `agenda_params` that would be passed into the changeset in the controller action would look like:

```
%{
  "id" => "default_agenda",
  "name" => "Default Agenda",
  "pages" => [
    %{
      "content" => "<p>foo</p>",
      "duration" => 10,
      "id" => "0849862a-0794-4466-88a3-6052da360ca0"
    },
    %{
      "content" => "<p>bar</p>",
      "duration" => 15,
      "id" => "93387d2d-a6ed-4902-911f-4dc1525aca2b"
    }
  ]
}
```

But trying to run this data through my update action produces the error. Can anyone offer some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the following does not look right:

```
%MyApp.Agenda{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:built, "agenda">,
 id: "default_agenda", name: "Default Agenda",
 pages: [%{"content" => "<p>This is the default agenda</p>", "duration" => 10,
"id" => "0849862a-0794-4466-88a3-6052da360ca0"},
%{"content" => "<p>Nice to see you</p>", "duration" => 15,
"id" => "93387d2d-a6ed-4902-911f-4dc1525aca2b"}]}
```

The `pages` list should be a list of AgendaPage structs, not maps as you can see from my example below. I'm not sure how you ended up with that.

However, the main issue seems to be providing the `id` field in your params. I had the same issue when trying to update an existing record based on your sample params above. Hoever, if you drop the id field from the params on the update, it works.

Here is a working example:

```
iex(4)> {:ok, ag} = Repo.insert Agenda.changeset(%Agenda{id: "default_agenda"}, %{name: "Default Agenda"})
[debug] QUERY OK db=9.7ms
INSERT INTO "agendas" ("id","name","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) ["default_agenda", "Default Agenda", {{2017, 7, 21}, {23, 43, 46, 739178}}, {{2017, 7, 21}, {23, 43, 46, 747000}}]
{:ok,
 %Playground.Demo.Agenda{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "agendas">,
  id: "default_agenda", inserted_at: ~N[2017-07-21 23:43:46.739178],
  name: "Default Agenda", pages: [],
  updated_at: ~N[2017-07-21 23:43:46.747000]}}
iex(5)> Repo.update Agenda.changeset(ag, %{
...(5)>   "name" => "Default Agenda",
...(5)>   "pages" => [
...(5)>     %{
...(5)>       "content" => "<p>foo</p>",
...(5)>       "duration" => 10,
...(5)>       "id" => "0849862a-0794-4466-88a3-6052da360ca0"
...(5)>     },
...(5)>     %{
...(5)>       "content" => "<p>bar</p>",
...(5)>       "duration" => 15,
...(5)>       "id" => "93387d2d-a6ed-4902-911f-4dc1525aca2b"
...(5)>     }
...(5)>   ]
...(5)> }
...(5)> )
[debug] QUERY OK db=15.7ms
UPDATE "agendas" SET "pages" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "id" = $3 [[%{content: "<p>foo</p>", duration: 10, id: "e7b5b7d9-9308-43f0-8bc7-c5956640772b"}, %{content: "<p>bar</p>", duration: 15, id: "1c668d06-5c60-4a4d-a052-43520597162d"}], {{2017, 7, 21}, {23, 44, 23, 752892}}, "default_agenda"]
{:ok,
 %Playground.Demo.Agenda{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "agendas">,
  id: "default_agenda", inserted_at: ~N[2017-07-21 23:43:46.739178],
  name: "Default Agenda",
  pages: [%Playground.Demo.AgendaPage{content: "<p>foo</p>", duration: 10,
    id: "e7b5b7d9-9308-43f0-8bc7-c5956640772b"},
   %Playground.Demo.AgendaPage{content: "<p>bar</p>", duration: 15,
    id: "1c668d06-5c60-4a4d-a052-43520597162d"}],
  updated_at: ~N[2017-07-21 23:44:23.752892]}}
iex(6)> Repo.get Agenda, "default_agenda"
[debug] QUERY OK source="agendas" db=7.2ms
SELECT a0."id", a0."name", a0."pages", a0."inserted_at", a0."updated_at" FROM "agendas" AS a0 WHERE (a0."id" = $1) ["default_agenda"]
%Playground.Demo.Agenda{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "agendas">,
 id: "default_agenda", inserted_at: ~N[2017-07-21 23:43:46.739178],
 name: "Default Agenda",
 pages: [%Playground.Demo.AgendaPage{content: "<p>foo</p>", duration: 10,
   id: "e7b5b7d9-9308-43f0-8bc7-c5956640772b"},
  %Playground.Demo.AgendaPage{content: "<p>bar</p>", duration: 15,
   id: "1c668d06-5c60-4a4d-a052-43520597162d"}],
 updated_at: ~N[2017-07-21 23:44:23.752892]}
iex(7)>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right - there seems to be a problem with the schema. I need to backtrack a little bit, will keep you posted. I had a hunch about the `id` issue but wasn't sure. Steve, you the man!

Comment: Steve, you've pointed me in the right direction, though I still have to figure out exactly how to solve it. The crux of it is that, when I get the inserted record, it is not preserving the references to the embedded model - I'm getting `pages: [%{"content"...` instead of `pages: [%MyApp.AgendaPage{"content"...`. The `id` issue was also a problem, but this is the main problem. I'm actually not using Postgres - using an experimental DynamoDB adapter... so need to figure out how to preserve that structure.

Comment: I was able to make a successful update by manually adding the model reference to the first argument passed to the changeset. Steve, thanks a million for your perspective!